# Integral with complex variable

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, indefinite-integrals, contour-integration, complex-integration

I want to compute

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x+yi +2}} dy 
$$
where $i$ is the imaginary number. How to compute this integral??

Comment: multiply by $\frac{\sqrt{x+2-iy}}{\sqrt{x+2-iy}}$

Comment: It looks divergent (decays too slowly as $y \to \pm\infty$). Why do you need to compute this?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x+yi +2}} dy = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x+yi +2}}\frac{\sqrt{x+2-iy}}{\sqrt{x+2-iy}}dy=...
$$

Comment: ....but be careful with your choice of branches

Comment: @tired: Can you explain it little bit more. How the choice of branch come here?